# RxBleConnection with PublishSubject not releasing connection

Tags: rx-java, rxandroidble

My app effectively has a queue of BLE operations to perform with my peripheral.  Each operation begins by establishing a connection to the peripheral, which returns `Observable<RxBleConnection>`.  The first item in the queue initiates the connection, and the subsequent operations simply receive this (shared) `RxBleConnection`.

In simplied form, the queue is executed via:

```
Observable.concatDelayError(queuedOperations)
```

If the connection cannot be established, or it is dropped during one operation, the remaining queued operations each retry, which attempt to re-establish the connection.

I decided to modify the behavior such that once the connection became invalid, the queued operations should always receive the now-invalid `RxBleConnection` rather than re-establishing a new connection.  The retry logic is still executed but fails immediately in these instances --- there are other reasons the operation can fail, which have nothing to do with the connection.

To produce this behavior, I compose a `PublishSubject` directly after the `Observable<RxBleConnection>`.  This subject simply delegates the original `RxBleConnection` --- see code below.  If the connection reaches an error state, then subsequent subscriptions to the subject will get the error; otherwise, the shared connection is returned.  This is exactly the behavior I wanted, and it appears to work as designed when an error occurs; however, I am having problems now when everything succeeds.

Before the change, once all the operations in the queue were consumed, the connection was automatically released. With the addition of the `PublishSubject`, though, the operations are successful, but the connection remains open.  Using debugging statements, I verified that the subject's `onUnsubscribe` and `onTerminate` are never called.  The original `RxBleConnection` eventually times out --- and its `onUnsubscribe` and `onTerminate` do get called.

Was wondering what I am doing incorrectly that is causing the app to remain connected to the peripheral.

```
private Observable.Transformer<RxBleConnection, RxBleConnection> createConnectionSubject() {
    return rxBleConnectionObservable -> {
        final PublishSubject<RxBleConnection> subject = PublishSubject.create();

        rxBleConnectionObservable.subscribe(
            subject::onNext,
            subject::onError,
            subject::onCompleted);

        return subject;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `PublishSubject` does not pass the unsubscription event to the upstream.

Maybe you should check out the `ConnectionSharingAdapter` class?